# Highstocks - Step line does not appear on chart export

Tags: highcharts

I refer to: http://jsfiddle.net/e4c1hLmo/1/. The following contains the objects for the 3 series.

```
{
    "name": "Step Series 1",
    "data": [{
        "x": 1323532800000,
        "y": 5
    }, {
        "x": 1418227200000,
        "y": 5
    }],
    "step": true,
    "color": "#0000ff",
    "id": "stepSeries1",
    "yAxis": "testAxis"
},{
    "data": [................],
    "color": "#000000",
    "type": "line",
    "name": "Test Series 1",
    "yAxis": "testAxis",
    "id": "testSeries1"
},{
    "name": "Step Series 2",
    "data": [{
        "x": 1323532800000,
        "y": 4
    }, {
        "x": 1418227200000,
        "y": 4
    }],
    "step": true,
    "color": "#f1c232",
    "id": "stepSteries2",
    "yAxis": "testAxis"
}
```

Currently, when we perform the chart export, "Step Series 2" does not seem to appear. Now, when I swap the order of the series object around, all the series will appear during export.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: The step line is not visible, because on chart is also hidden.

Comment: The step lines are the ones in blue and yellow, they are visible when we generate the chart. However, if we were to export the chart, you'll notice that the chart only has 2 series instead of 3.

Comment: One again, in scenario when your range (on navigator) is set where yellow line is not displayed, exported image doesnt display this line. If you expand it for entire range, yellow line is exported. So let me know what is wrong?

Comment: Oh, I think I got what you meant. Is there any rationale behind why would be yellow line only be exported  if we expand it for entire range? It seems that the yellow line is also existent on the chart even if we do not expand to the entire range on the navigator.

Comment: Please see my comment above, line is not exported because is not visible on chart range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of the `min` and `max` value you set for the `xAxis`. The `datetime` values for `Step Series 1` and `Step Series 2` are not specifically in that range. I commented the lines and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/e4c1hLmo/7/

Comment: Thank you Raeen! Your explanation is clear and concise.